# Create a child Actor based on the received message ID

Tags: akka

The parent actor creates a child actor based on the identity in the received message, and the same message ID will reuse the child actor. What should I do? I am using this way now.

```scala
override def receive: Receive = {
    case location: DeviceLocationInfo =>
       log.info(s"$location")
     val settings = CacheBasicAlarmSettingInRedis(system)
       .memoizeInRedisBasicAlarmSetting(location.deviceId)
     settings foreach { setting =>
      val actorRef = context.child(location.deviceId)
        .getOrElse(context.actorOf(Props(new OverSpeedAlarm),location.deviceId))
      actorRef ! location
     }

    case _ =>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar pattern all the time. Have a Map that uses the device ID as the key and an ActorRef as the value -- if there's no entry in the map for a given device ID, create a new child; if there is an entry for a given device ID, then forward the message to the child.